# Why do Django custom validation messages not display on the HTML page?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have the following custom username validation method. This method is executed when I submit the form, but it does not display the error message. However, other default field validations are working fine.

```py
def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data['username']

    if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("This username already taken. please choose another.")

    return username
```

Here is the HTML code for the username input:

```html
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username" required>
<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
    {{ form.username.errors.0 }}
</span>
```